# Get an output after a select option in html

Tags: php, mysqli

So basically, i have a database that simulates an airport, and i want to make a page that after a selected category i provide the total amount of customs fees of the category(example: category selected=electronics, output wanted= eletronics = somenumber) the select tag in the html is dynamic based on the category(so if i remove a category the select option disappears). The problem is that i don't know how to display the amount. I've managed to display the selected option but i have no idea on how to pair the amount with the category.

Sorry for the messy explaination, but it's really hard for me to explain my problem in another language, please help a poor student

For any doubts about the code just ask

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Dazi</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="home.php" method="GET">
      <select name="categoria" id="cate">
<?php
$conn = MySQLi_connect("localhost","root","","aeroporto");

if (!$conn)
    die("Problems");


 $query = "select CA.descrizione as 'categoria', sum(C.dazio) as 'qta_dazi'
      from controlli C inner join merci M on C.id=M.id_controllo_fk inner join categorie CA on CA.id=C.id
      group by CA.id";

 $res=MySQLi_query($conn ,$query);

 while( $row= MySQLi_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {
     $c=$row["categoria"];
     $n=$row["qta_dazi"];
     $cat=$_GET["categoria"];

     echo "<option value='$c'>$c</option>";

 }

 echo"</select>"; 
 echo"<input type='submit' value='Visualizza il totale'>";
 echo"<br><br><br>";

 if(isset($cat)){
     echo $cat." =";
 }


 $ok= MySQLi_close($conn);
 if (!$ok)
   die("problems");

 ?>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The problem is i don't know how to display $n  after echo $cat." ="; because if i put $n in the statement obviously it display the last value

Comment: can you share your table structure.

Comment: Hi Rogi, have a look at my answer and ask me any clarification if you would need.

Answer (score 0):

During the loop, check if `$c` ever equals `$cat` (note that you can set $cat outside the loop, since it does not change as a result of the DB query). At that point, set a separate variable (which has scope outside the loop) to denote the matching amount, and use that in your display:

```
$cat=$_GET["categoria"];
$val = "";

while( $row= MySQLi_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
     $c=$row["categoria"];
     $n=$row["qta_dazi"];
     if ($c == $cat) $val = $n; //check the category value from the DB against the GET variable.
     echo "<option value='$c'>$c</option>";
}

echo"</select>"; 
echo"<input type='submit' value='Visualizza il totale'>";
echo"<br><br><br>";

if(isset($cat)) {
    echo $cat." = ".$val;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

*Just for didactical purpose, do not use this in production.*

In home.php:

```
$categoryId = $_REQUEST['categoria'];
//sanitization...

$conn = MySQLi_connect("localhost","root","","aeroporto");

//...

 $query = "select sum(C.dazio) as 'prezzo_dazi', count(C.dazio) as 'qta_dazi'
      from controlli C join categorie CA on CA.id = C.id WHERE CA.id = $categoryId";

$res=MySQLi_query($conn ,$query);

if( $row = MySQLi_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo "Dazi: {$row['prezzo_dazi']} € (qt. {$row['qta_dazi']}";
}else{
    echo "Categories doesn't have any Dazio assigned.";
}

MySQLi_close($conn);
```

Usually a small attention o research on Google it's enough to have an higher understanding of the programming concept.

Cheers.